# Use fscanf to read from given line

Tags: c, input, scanf

I want read a txt file that has up to 10 lines. The file is formatted like this on all lines:

```
1 1 8
2 2 3
3 1 15
4 2 7
```

I'm trying to write a function that will read from only the line provided by an int passed to it. I thought of using a for loop to iterate through the lines without scanning anything but I can't figure out how to implement that.

My function so far looks like this, the for loop has not been implemented properly yet.

```
void process(int lineNum, char *fullName)
  {
    int ii, num1, num2, num3;

    FILE* f; 
    f = fopen(fullName, "r");

    if(f==NULL) 
      {
      printf("Error: could not open %S", fullName);
      }

    else
    {
    for (ii=0 (ii = 0; ii < (lineNum-1); ii++)
      {
      /*move through lines without scanning*/
      fscanf(f, "%d %d %d", &num1, &num2, &num3);
      }

    printf("Numbers are: %d %d %d \n",num1, num2, num3);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were nearly done but you simply need to change the format specifier.The following code reads through the lines preceding your intended line,but ignores what it reads.

```
for (ii=0 (ii = 1; ii < (lineNum-1); ii++)
      {
      /*move through lines without scanning*/
      fscanf(f, "%*d %*d %*d%*c");
      // fscanf(f, "%*d %*d %*d\n");
      }
fscanf(f,"%d%d%d",&num1,&num2,&num3);
```

Comment: You need to check the result of `fscanf()` each time.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler `You need to check the result of fscanf() each time`--Can you clarify what you mean?I didn't get you.

Comment: Somehow the correct values are not getting scanned when I use above code. It always shows as 0.

Comment: Well, with the three `%*d` conversion specifications, you might get a return value of EOF if you encountered EOF before reaching the specified line.  You've no way of know that the first line contained a letter instead of a digit, unfortunately, until you run the extra `fscanf()`.  You should test the last `fscanf()` too; you might get EOF, or 0 or 1 or 2 (all of which indicate problems), or you might get 3 indicating success with 3 conversions. Note that adding `\n` to the format means blank lines will be skipped, but that was going to happen anyway; `%d` skips white space to the first digit.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to read all the lines up to the one you want.

I'd probably use `fgets()` to read the lines and `sscanf()` to parse the required line.  However, you can add a loop to read the unwanted lines (still `fgets()`) and then read the line you want with `fscanf()`.  Do check that you got three values: you must check the return value from `fscanf()`. Also remember to close the file you opened.

```
void process(int lineNum, char *fullName)
{
    FILE *f = fopen(fullName, "r");

    if (f == NULL) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: could not open %S", fullName);
        return;
    }

    int num1, num2, num3;
    for (int i = 0; i < lineNum; i++)
    {
        if (fscanf(f, "%d %d %d", &num1, &num2, &num3) != 3)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Format error on line %d\n", i+1);
            fclose(f);
            return;
        }
    }

    printf("Numbers are: %d %d %d \n",num1, num2, num3);
    fclose(f);
}
```

Note that this code does not actually enforce lines separating the sets of numbers (one of the disadvantages of the file-based members of the `scanf()` family of functions.  For that, you need `fgets()` and `sscanf()`:

```
void process(int lineNum, char *fullName)
{
    FILE *f = fopen(fullName, "r");

    if (f == NULL) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: could not open %S", fullName);
        return;
    }

    char line[4096];
    for (i = 0; i < lineNum; i++)
    {
        if (fgets(line, sizeof(line), f) == 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Premature EOF at line %d\n", i+1);
            fclose(f);
            return;
        }
        // Optionally check format here...
    }

    int num1, num2, num3;
    if (sscanf(line, "%d %d %d", &num1, &num2, &num3) != 3)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Format error on line %d\n", i+1);
        fclose(f);
        return;
    }

    printf("Numbers are: %d %d %d \n",num1, num2, num3);
    fclose(f);
}
```

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Is there any other way we can read but ignore entire lines like I clumsily did with `fscanf(f,"%*d%*d%*d")`?Is using `%*[^\n]` the nearest thing one can do for this?

Comment: @Rüppell'sVulture: The best way to skip whole lines is to use `fgets()`, as in the last version of the code in my answer.  Obviously, there's an outside chance it will miscount lines if any of those lines is longer than 4095 bytes.  OTOH, that's fairly improbable.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I have a confusion now and I don't want to put it in a question.So can you tell me this--`fscanf()` ignores whitespace automatically,so after the first line,when three integers are read and ignored according to my `%*d%*d%*d` specifier,I expect `fscanf()` to ignore the newline too when it starts reading in the next run of the loop.But **why doesn't** my additional `%*c` or `\n` cause problem and the program runs fine when I use `%*d%*d%*d%*c` or `%*d%*d%*d\n` in my code?

Comment: You can't tell where anything went wrong with those formats; you can detect EOF, but otherwise, `fscanf()` will return 0.  However, since the `%*d` skips leading white space — including newlines — it doesn't much matter whether you read the newline after the third number with the `%*c` or not, and when you have `\n` there, that's a white space so the read skips the newline and any trailing or leading white space, stopping when it reaches a non-white space character.  Of course, you could also have newlines in the middle of the three numbers, or you could have more than three numbers on a line.

Comment: Note that the trailing `\n` in the format is particularly weird when the user is typing at the terminal. They hit return but it doesn't continue until they type a non-blank. This is why `fscanf()` is so difficult to use when the data is not reliable.  When it's reliable, it's easy, but if anything goes wrong, diagnostics and recovery are painful. That's why it is better to use `fgets()` and `sscanf()`; you have control over what is being parsed, you can try again with a different format if you want to, and you can report the whole line, not just what `fscanf()` has not managed to interpret.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use checks for your input scans. you might potentially run into errors or EOF.

```
if(line < 1)       //check for invalid line number
{
    printf("Invalid line number..aborting\n");
    exit(1);   //aborting is optional
}
for(int i = 0;i<line-1;i++)
{
    switch(flag  = fscanf(fp,"%*d %*d %*d"))//flag is for debug only
    {
    case 0 ://since we are ignoring the read, fscanf return 0
    case 3:break;           //normal read (should not happen)
    default:printf("File read Error\n");//if fscanf returns EOF, 1,2
    }
}
if(EOF ==fscanf(fp,"%d%d%d",&n1,&n2,&n3))//check for EOF. last scan might have ignored till last line
{
    printf("File read Error: end of file reached");
}
else
{
    printf("\n%d, %d, %d",n1,n2,n3);//normal case
}
```