# Using fscanf to check if more lines exist

Tags: c, input, scanf

I have this function to read numbers from txt files that are structured like so:

```
1 2 5
2 1 9
3 5 8
```

The function reads the values correctly into my values, but I want to check if the line I have read is the last in the file.

My last if statement in the below function attempts to do this by seeing if fscanf produces NULL but it doesn't work, the function always returns NULL even if it's not the last line.

```
 void process(int lineNum, char *fullName)
      {
        int ii, num1, num2, num3;

        FILE* f; 
        f = fopen(fullName, "r");

        if(f==NULL) 
          {
          printf("Error: could not open %S", fullName);
          }

        else
        {
        for (ii=0 (ii = 0; ii < (lineNum-1); ii++)
          {
          /*move through lines without scanning*/
          fscanf(f, "%d %d %d", &num1, &num2, &num3);
          }

        if (fscanf(f, "%*d %*d %*d\n")==NULL)
            {
            printf("No more lines");
            }

        fclose(f);

        }
      }
```

Comment: check my code too user :)

Comment: you should have checked your previous post i have given you the answer with detectinf EOF and errors.:-) [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16557700/1825795)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `feof()` to check if you are reading past the end of the file.

From man page of `fscanf`:

> RETURN VALUE
>          These functions return the number of input items  successfully  matched
>          and assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero in the
>          event of an early matching failure.

You if the last line that you are trying to read is not in the expected format, `fscanf` may not read anything and return `0` which is same as `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks feof worked for me: 

if (feof(f))
 {
 printf("No more lines\n");
 }

Comment: -1 NO -- `feof` only tells you if you've attempted to read PAST the end of the file.  If you've exactly read the entire file but haven't yet had a read call fail, `feof` will return false.

Answer (score 1):

Check this below code.Using this code u can see whether you have reached the end of file or not.It is not suggested to use fscanf to read the end of file.

/* feof example: byte counter */

```
#include <stdio.h>

 int main ()
{
 FILE * pFile;
 int n = 0;
 pFile = fopen ("myfile.txt","r");
 if (pFile==NULL) perror ("Error opening file");
 else
  {
   while (fgetc(pFile) != EOF) {
  ++n;
  }
 if (feof(pFile)) {
  puts ("End-of-File reached.");
  printf ("Total number of bytes read: %d\n", n);
  }
 else puts ("End-of-File was not reached.");
  fclose (pFile);
}
return 0;
}
```